# Background Fetch - Concept /Understanding

Tags: ios, background-process

I'm developing an application that needs to fetch data approximately every 60 minutes and I thought that background fetch would be ideally suited. I've developed an application that when run in xCode and I simulate a background fetch works as expected, but when run on the device doesn't appear to work. I've also downloaded a couple of demonstration apps, all of which work in the simulator but not on the device, I'm incrementing the badge count.

The question is more related to the concept of background fetch, is it suited for what I need?

1. Does background fetch work when in background and also when the screen is locked?
2. Background fetch doesn't work when the application is in foreground, is this correct, if so I'll implement NSTimer. What happens when in foreground but the device locks the screen?
3. Background adjusts it's update period based on application usage, initially I set setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval to 60 but even when set to 5 background fetch never runs on the device
4. Application settings are correct and show that background fetch is enabled / allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Your app enters background state whenever the screen is locked(even if the app is in foreground). And whenever *- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application* is called, there's a chance that Background fetch can happen depending on how free the OS is. Fetch interval is not always accurate. During the 60th minute of your interval, if the OS is not free, the fetch won't happen. Make sure your app is in the background of your device and use *UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum* instead of specifying a 60 min interval. Fetch is more likely to happen.